# redirect all calls made to a folder to a file in root directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I seem to be unable to figure this out

I want to redirect all calls made to  /post/example-title to post.php file in root directory while preserving url. Ill be using the example-title to retrieve data from the db.

my hatches currently looks like so

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/[^.]*$ $1.php [NC,L]
```